# Javascript - Use of onclick property

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and just trying to understand the language better.
I was having some trouble using the onclick function and figure out how to make it work - however I'm hoping someone could explain to me why my code in line 2 doesn't work (i've tried "reveal;" "reveal();" and "reveal(this);" ) but line 3 works.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8YlEDwABSvvGDBcotFSE

```
var clickButton = document.getElementById("button");
clickButton.onclick = reveal(this); // this code doesn't work
//clickButton.setAttribute("onClick", "reveal(this)"); // but this one does
function reveal(obj) {
this.obj = obj;
obj.innerHTML = "X";
}
```

Thank you and much appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: the `this` being passed to it is more than likely the reference `[Window]` object. Also, you should use something like `clickButton.addEventListener('click', reveal)` instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Possible duplicate: [How does the “this” keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). In your example, if you need more information about `this`. Try to add `console.log(obj)` in `reveal` function to check what's happen in the console.

Answer (score 1):

The argument being passed to reveal will be an event. You can access the element via `event.target`. You don't need to access `this` at all. Please remember that setting `.onclick` via JavaScript is considered bad practice.

Working:

```
var clickButton = document.getElementById("button");

clickButton.onclick = reveal;

function reveal(event) {
    event.target.innerHTML = "X";
}
```

Better, using addEventListener:

```
var clickButton = document.getElementById("button");

clickButton.addEventListener("click", reveal);

function reveal(event) {
    event.target.innerHTML = "X";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### First:

The `onclick` property should hold a reference to a function that will be called when the event occur. You are not assigning a reference to a function, you are assigning the return value of that function (by executing it). This is how you do it:

```
clickButton.onclick = reveal; // assigning the reference to the function reveal not its return value (which is undefined by the way, because it returns nothing)
```

#### Second:

The only parameter passed to  event listeners is an event object. If you want to get the object that fired the event you should access the `target` property of that event object like this:

```
function reveal(ev) { // reveal will get only one argument which is the event object
    var elementThatFiredTheEvent = ev.target; // ev.target will be the DOM element that fired the event

    // do stuff with elementThatFiredTheEvent like changing the innerHTML ...
}
```